# Random variable distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

2 cards are drawn from a 52 card deck. The random variable X represents the number of aces drawn. The random variable distribution:

X = 0 : P(0) = 0.849

X = 1 : P(1) = 0.145

X = 2 : P(2) = 0.005

Is this how you do it?

---

Probability of the draws:

**0 aces out of 2 cards:**

C(48,2) * C(4,0) / C(52,2)

1128 / 1328 = 0.849

**1 ace out of 2 cards:**

C(48,1) * C(4,1) / C(52,2)

48 * 4 / 1328 = 0.145

**2 aces out of 2 cards:**

C(48,0) * C(4,2) / C(52,2)

6 / 1328 = 0.005

Comment: The probabilities should add up to 1, and yours add up only to 1326/1328.

Comment: So just a rounding error? But my probability calculations are sound?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a rounding error, since you are showing fractions (not decimals) that don't add up to 1. So you may want to re-check your numbers along the lines of the answer given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of $X=x$ is given by

$$\Pr(X=x)=\frac{\binom{4}{x}\binom{52-4}{2-x}}{\binom{52}{2}}$$

where $X\in[0,2]$.

This gives:
$$\Pr(X=0)=\frac{188}{221}\approx 0.8507$$
$$\Pr(X=1)=\frac{32}{221}\approx 0.1448$$
$$\Pr(X=2)=\frac{1}{221}\approx 0.0045$$